# Deleting a step from a list using the step name

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having some trouble with deleting a preprocessing step from a list using the name of the step, alternatively i can easily delete a step using the index value but how can i do the same with the name of the step

Code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline 

# list to which preprocessing steps will be added
preprocessing=[]

#appending MaxAbsScaler into the list 
preprocessing.append(('maxabs_scaler',
MaxAbsScaler(copy=1)))

#placing the list inside pipeline 
pipe=Pipeline(preprocessing)

#deleting MaxAbsScaler from the list
#this crashes 
preprocessing.pop('maxabs_scaler')

print(preprocessing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can first find index of your item:

```
ind = [t[0] for t in preprocessing].index('maxabs_scaler')
```

then delete item:

```
del preprocessing[ind]
```

Comment: That works! , never thought of using this with a step